# calculate speed of vehicle using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a project that I have to calculate speed of vehicle in a camera traffic. I used Background subtraction algorithm to get the foreground (moving object). after I got foreground, centroid, boudaries of each object, I have to calculate the speed of each object. to do that, I will calculate the distance the each vehicle moved in a time. but  the problem is in next frame I don't know what is the object in previous frame.  I can not identify exactly 1 vehicle for 2 consecutive frames. who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mean shift algorithm:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift

[Image Segmentation using Mean Shift explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831813/image-segmentation-using-mean-shift-explained)

Answer (score 0):

You probably find [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) useful for your purposes, also you can do with SURF features.

Comment: yes, thanks so much Dinl but It is using computervision tool and I can't control that code. if I write that code into a m file, It run good. but when I write each part of that program (Create System Objects, Initialize Tracks, ....) to a m file separately. (such as a subfunction) then I run main function (multiObjectTracking()), It is Error. may you help me?